# Can I use wp-cli to create posts with a custom post types?

Tags: wp-cli

I regularly need to create a batch of posts of a custom post type, with names and meta values that follow a regular pattern. This seems like a perfect canditate for using wp-cli, but so far it hasn't worked.

Using wp-cli, if I enter:

```
wp post create --post_title='test' --post_status='draft' post_type='class_notes'
```

I get an error:

> Unable to read content from 'post_type=class_notes'.

However wp-cli is definitely able to connect to this post type, as the following returns a proper list of labels and capabilities:

```
wp post-type get 'class_notes'
```

Is it the case that I simply cannot create a post with a custom post type using wp-cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should probably be

`wp post create --post_title='test' --post_status='draft' --post_type='class_notes'`

(note the two `--` that mark it as a command option)

Comment: Ah, you got it. Thanks so much. My face is a little red now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/generate/ to generate how posts you need (for testing purpose for example)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's not really a direct answer to what I was trying to do, but it's a useful resource all the same.